# Cakephp: Ajax-request goes to the action it's called from when another url is specified

Tags: jquery, routes, cakephp-2.0

I'm sorry for the unpresice title, but I'm having trouble describing my problem without showing some code.

I have an action - edit_one - which is defined in routes.php like this:

```
Router::connect('/edit_one/:ad_id', array('controller' => 'ads', 'action' => 'edit_one'));
```

As you can see it takes a parameter - ad_id.

I have an jQuery-ajax function in the edit_one view, like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "delete_from_facebook",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function (res) {
            console.log(res);
       }
       });
```

The url 'delete_from_facebook' is defined in routes.php like this:

```
Router::connect('/delete_from_facebook', array('controller' => 'ads', 'action' => 'deleteFromFacebook'));
```

The deleteFromFacebook function in the Controller:

```
public function deleteFromFacebook() {
    $this->autorender = false;
    try {

        $this->log($this->request->data, 'debug');
        $response = $this->fb_handler->deletePhotoFromFacebook($this->fb, $this->request->data['id']);
        $this->log($response, 'debug');

        return new CakeResponse(array('body' => json_encode($response)));
    } catch (FacebookApiException $fbe) {
        $this->showFacebookAPIException($fbe);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $msg = __('An error has occured while uploading images. Please try again.');
        $this->showException($e, $msg);
    }
}
```

My problem is that the ajax-request will always post to the edit_one action, IF the url is relative. If the url provided is absolute it will post to deleteFromFacebook function.

I know the reason for this. It's because the edit_one action takes a parameter. I've tried it without, then the ajax-request goes to the right place. I'm using the same ajax-request from the view to make an ad, which is defined in the routes.php like this:

```
Router::connect('/add', array('controller' => 'ads', 'action' => 'add'));
```

As you can see from the routes, add.ctp and edit_one.ctp is in same folder. A relative path should work just as well from both.

I must have the parameter and I have to use a relative path. What can I do to get the ajax-request to post to the right place?

Comment: Are you iffy about mixing php with js? Because what I normally do with url in js is adding <?=$this->Html->url($your_url_array)?>, but maybe you want another more elegant solution...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I would rather get to the bottom of this in another way. This seems like a rather strange issue.

Answer (score 0):

To what url the ajax request is made is solely dependent on your jquery code. It has nothing to do with CakePHP routes. Stop using relative url in your jquery code and your problem is gone. A common sensible way is have the base path of your app in a js var and then append that var to all url strings used in your js code. Eg.

```
//At the top of a js file load in all your pages or in all page <head>
var baseUrl = "/";  // OR "/subfolder/"

$.ajax({
        url: baseUrl + "delete_from_facebook",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function (res) {
            console.log(res);
       }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but this must have something to do with CakePHP. As I said, I've tested the exact same ajax-request without the parameter in the route, and from another view-file placed in the same folder which does not require a parameter. No other variables changed. I tested it several times, and the results are consistent:

When the parameter is required, it does NOT work.
When it is not, it works.

The main reason I asked this question is because this seems like a strange issue, and I would like to get to the bottom of why this happens.Common practice, or not.

Comment: Using `url: "delete_from_facebook"` check the url called in your browser console and you will know why.

Comment: delete_from_facebook is routed, as I said. That means that it's an "alias", if you would, for another url; baseurl (which cakephp knows) + /ads/delete_from_facebook. (Controller/action) In the console when parameter is required: baseurl/one_edit/delete_from_facebook. When not required: baseurl/delete_from_facebook. 
I'm sorry if I misled you with my talk about relative urls, delete_from_facebook is actually an absolute one provided by cakes routing. Still, if I write the absolute path in jquery, it works, which is very strange to me. I'd understand if it was consistent with add.ctp, but no.

Comment: I see now that you are a core contributor to cakePHP, so I'm sorry if I was patronizing you. I'm sure you know what you're talking about, but it would be great if you can explain this to a newbie like me. This is not clear to me yet.